# Notify_url Not Working / Being Called

Tags: php, paypal

I have multiple websites, each website as the its own PayPal account (not owned by me), for 1 particular customer when a person pays for a product they are sent to PayPal make their payment, once the payment is complete, it should submit to the notify_url - return/cancelled etc works fine - but the notify_url is not being called.

On a different website, different PayPal account (this is a business account), the notify_url works.

Both sites uses the same code, but the code is correct (otherwise it wouldn't work for the 2nd), i have checked the url of the 1st notify_url and it is correct no errors etc.

How can it work for 1 PayPal account, but not the other?

Comment: check if you have any script errors in second ipn url..  best post your ipn script which is not processing ..

Comment: There is no script errors, it's just not being launched, as in the php code i have made it email me the $_REQUEST, before it does any PayPal related items (such as capture transaction id)

Comment: I have just changed the PayPal account, for the first website (using the same as the 2nd website) and it worked - therefore it's something wrong with the PayPal account of the first website